# P is a point in triangle $ABC$, what is $[APC]$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

> **Moderator Note:** This question is part of an ongoing contest on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/i/G1XngR/), and will be unlocked in 1 week.

P is a point in triangle $ABC$. The lines $AP$,$BP$, and $CP$ intersect the sides $BC$,$CA$, and $AB$ at points $D$,$E$, and $F$, respectively.

If $[BDP]=10$, $[DPC]=16$, $[APB]=210$, what is $[APC]$?

Comment: Could you explain your notation such as $[ABC]$ ?

Comment: This is a question taken from [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/i/G1XngR/). In it, it is explained that $[PQRS]$ denotes the area of the figure $PQRS$.

Answer (score 1):

The line segments $BD$ and $DC$ are in the ratio $10$ to $16$, because with respect to these bases $\triangle BDP$ and $\triangle DPC$ have the same height.

So the areas of $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$ are in the same ratio (bases $BD$ and $DC$, same height) and therefore by subtraction so are the areas of $\triangle APB$ and $\triangle APC$.

It follows that $\triangle APC$ has area $210\cdot \frac{16}{10}$.

Comment: This is a question taken from [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/i/G1XngR/) current set of problems.  Please close the discussion and reopen it on 5/1. Thanks.